# Getting error when setting up NATS Account resolver --> nats-server: operators do not allow Accounts to be configured directly

Tags: yaml, nats.io, nats-streaming-server, nats-jetstream

Hi I am trying to set the NATS account resolver according to these instructions: [Artifact Hub Upgrade Nodes](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/nats/nats)

Here is my config:

```
nats:
jetstream:
enabled: true

cluster:
  enabled: true
  name: "nats"
  replicas: 3

auth:
enabled: true
systemAccount: 
resolver:
  type: full
  operator: 
  systemAccount: 
  resolverPreload:
```

I have left out the user and the jwt information

When I start up the NATS server with that config I get the following error:
**nats-server: operators do not allow Accounts to be configured directly**